# Python: Работа с файлами

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть текстовый файл 1.txt https://dropmefiles.com/X9ofc и из него надо сделать такой 2.txt https://dropmefiles.com/xnNlu

Надо вытащить отсюда(1.txt) информацию и структурировать ее таким образом. Просто где значение Lat их в одну колонку, а где стоит Lon в другую колонку. и закинуть эту инфу в новый текстовый файл - чтобы вышло вот это.

```
-
Long        Lat
39.55577100 42.25142500
42.59824700 42.64250200
39.97199200 40.77315900
42.95417700 41.16786400
-
```

Буду очень признателен если поможете.

Я - начинающий программист. Сейчас пытаюсь сделать это плевое задание(казалось-бы). Дошел только к тому чтобы скопировать данный из одного текстового дока и вставить их в другой. Как провести проверку елементов одного документа .txt и при условии *ТРУ* вытянуть информацию - это для меня загадка. Наверно надо как-то преобразовать етот текстовый документ в список и потом делать проверку, если так то не знаю как это сделать.

Comment: не помещайте необходимую информацию на другие ресурсы, если содержимое файла имеет отношение к вопросу, то вопрос его должен содержать (небольшой фрагмент). Также добавьте Вашу текущую попытку ([код](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) и явно укажите словами в чём проблема, если этот код запустить (если ошибка, то приведите её в вопросе полностью как текст, сохраняя форматирование)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Сам начинающий, поэтому очень простой вариант (сорри, первый раз здесь код размещаю, скорей всего напутаю с форматированием)

```
input = open('/1.txt', 'r')

# читаю инфу с файла, создаю два списка с помошью которых буду искать данные

A = input.read()
Z = A.split('\n')

BLong = ['LTLong', 'RTLong', 'LBLong', 'RBLong', 'CLong']
DataLong = [] # здесь будут координаты Long
BLat = ['LTLat', 'RTLat', 'LBLat', 'RBLat', 'CLat']
DataLat = [] # здесь будут координаты Lat

# вот поиск - нахожу строку из списка, и данные, следующие за ней заношу еще в два списка

for f in range(len(BLong)):
    f1 = Z.index(BLong[f])
    DataLong.append(Z[f1 + 1])
for z in range(len(BLat)):
    z1 = Z.index(BLat[z])
    DataLat.append(Z[z1 + 1])

# формирую строку для ввода в файл. В условии, в примере между данными - табуляция. Оставил еще две координаты с нулями, там тоже могут быть числа, если они не нужны, то поменять range(5) на range(4)

Kolonki = ''
for k in range(5):
    Kolonki += '\n' + DataLong[k] + '\t' + DataLat[k]

#запись в файл

output = open('/2.txt', 'w')
output.write('Long\tLat' + Kolonki)

input.close()
output.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ниже код, который записывает выборки по двум файлам.

Проблема в неизвестной последовательности входных данных.

После формирования двух файлов, их можно открыть и объединить в один файл.

Можно до файлов не доводить, а сформированные последовательности прочитать и записать в файл.

```
m=[]

f1 = open("D:/1.txt", "r")
v1 = open("D:/11.txt", "w")
v2 = open("D:/111.txt", "w")



for   line in f1.readlines():
      m.append(line)

poisk1="ong"


n=0
for   line in m:
      n=n+1
      if line[-4:-1] ==poisk1:
          v1.write(str(m[n]))

poisk1="Lat"
n=0
for   line in m:
      n=n+1
      if line[-4:-1] ==poisk1:
          v2.write(str(m[n]))

f1.close()
v1.close()
v2.close()
```